# How can I programmatically detect missing DLLs for LoadLibrary() or have Windows report them?

Tags: dll, windows-10, lazy-loading, loadlibrary

I want LoadLibrary() to show which DLLs are missing when it fails. According to the documentation, as long as you call SetErrorMode(0), Windows should automatically pop up an error message box showing the 1st missing DLL.

This does happen on Windows Server 2012: The program can't start because DLL2.dll is missing from your computer. Please reinstall the program to fix this problem

But it doesn't happen on Windows 10 Pro & Enterprise, and Windows 7 Enterprise. Is there some function or registry entry to turn it on? Or can I programmatically get the missing/unloadable DLL? GetLastError() doesn't seem to return that.

Some more details about what I'm trying to do. Earlier, all the DLLs used were loaded at startup. If a DLL couldn't load, there will be an error message in every version of Windows. Then I started using delay DLL loading which uses LoadLibrary(), but then the error message no longer shows, which is very frustrating for debugging problems in the field.

Comment: Not necessarily. Often, the DLL being loaded exists but 1 of its dependencies is missing or can't be loaded. I want to know that.

Comment: I think you are looking for LoadLibraryEx()

Comment: What is being returned by GetLastError()?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel, its already been done, use http://www.dependencywalker.com to figure this out.

Comment: But it would be impractical to ask users to use Dependency Walker to find the missing DLL(s)